# URDF transform to world fails

Tags: urdf, xacro, transform, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I am working on a project where i connect a robotiq 85 2f gripper to a ur10.
I did this by making an urdf (xacro) file that describes my toplevel system.
In the urdf I include the UR10 and gripper urdf.
Then i link them together as follows:

```
  <joint name="gripper_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="fts_robotside"/>
    <child link="robotiq_85_base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.03" rpy="1.5706 -1.5706 0.0" />   
  </joint>
```

When i launch the launch file which uploads this urdf to param server and launches rviz it gets weird.

My "robotiq_85_base_link" gets visualized like it should, but the links following: "robotiq_85_left_finger_link" "...left_finger_tip_link" "...right_finger_link" and "...right_finger_tip_link" are not displayed in rviz but instead appear in white at the center of the "world".

If i click my robot model it says:
"No transform from [robotiq_85_left_finger_link] to [world]" for all the links.
How can i fix this?

I noticed that if i make a static_transform_publish node where i connect the link tf's to the parents tf's it would work, but this is not the right way to do it is it?

Some general info:

ubuntu 16.04

ros kinetic

RViz version 1.12.17 (kinetic). Compiled against Qt version 5.5.1. Compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)

[UR10_urdf link](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/tree/kinetic-devel/ur_description/urdf)

[gripper_urdf link](https://github.com/crigroup/robotiq/tree/master/robotiq_description/urdf)

Kind regards
Jan Tromp.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322283/urdf-transform-to-world-fails/) by [Jan Tromp](https://answers.ros.org/users/40880/jan-tromp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:
I have found a workaroud for the problem.
I found out the problem was being caused by something going wrong in the grippers' finger joints.
I still haven't figured out what is exactly the problem but for my application the following work-around is enough for me:

I changed the gripper file and made all the joints fixed, then linked the gripper base to the sensor like this:

```
  <joint name="gripper_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="fts_robotside"/>
    <child link="robotiq_85_base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 -0.01 0.03" rpy="1.5706 -1.5706 0.0" />   
  </joint>
```

Then everything worked fine.
Note that this will make it so that the gripper cannot close anymore!

Kind regards,
Jan Tromp

---

Originally posted by [Jan Tromp](https://answers.ros.org/users/40880/jan-tromp/) with karma: 28 on 2019-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-07**:
Likely cause is that there are no `JointState` msgs published that contain the gripper's joints. That would result in no transforms published for those frames, leading to the error you showed.

**Comment by [Jan Tromp](https://answers.ros.org/users/40880/jan-tromp/) on 2019-05-08**:
Seems logic, but when I launch the launch file provided with the package, which uploads just the gripper connected to the world URDF, it does show properly.
No big deal though, i found a solution which will work for me.
And thanks for your response

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-08**:\

> when I launch the launch file provided with the package, which uploads just the gripper connected to the world URDF, it does show properly.

Which launch file? If that includes a `joint_state_publisher`, then that would again make sense, as a `joint_state_publisher` will publish "fake" joint states for all joints in your urdf.

**Comment by [Jan Tromp](https://answers.ros.org/users/40880/jan-tromp/) on 2019-05-09**:
Yes it does,
It uploads the URDF, starts joint_state_published node, starts robot_state_publisher node and starts rviz node
so in the end it does make sense :p
Thanks for your response!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-09**:
Perhaps you can update your answer, as what you posted is not actually an answer, but more of a work-around. If you don't care about the actual state of the gripper (ie: fingers) then changing all joints to be a `fixed` type is fine of course, but it seems like a rather large limitation to me, as your model will now not correspond to the real world.